# Flutter Build Fails: InAppWebView error: package okhttp3 does not exist

Tags: android, flutter, webview, youtube

**Description**
When adding youtube_player_flutter v8.0.0 (link: https://github.com/sarbagyastha/youtube_player_flutter) the Flutter (android) app fails to build with the following error log:

```dart
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:97: error: package okhttp3 does not exist
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
              ^
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:121: error: cannot find symbol

  public OkHttpClient httpClient;
         ^
  symbol:   class OkHttpClient
  location: class InAppWebView
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\content_blocker\ContentBlockerHandler.java:24: error: package okhttp3 does not exist
import okhttp3.Request;
              ^
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\content_blocker\ContentBlockerHandler.java:25: error: package okhttp3 does not exist
import okhttp3.Response;
              ^
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\Util.java:46: error: package okhttp3 does not exist

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
              ^
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\Util.java:175: error: cannot find symbol
  public static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
                ^
  symbol:   class OkHttpClient
  location: class Util
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:184: error: cannot find symbol
    httpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();
                     ^
  symbol:   class OkHttpClient
  location: class InAppWebView
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\content_blocker\ContentBlockerHandler.java:180: error: cannot find symbol
                            Request mRequest = new Request.Builder().url(urlHttps).build();
                            ^
  symbol:   class Request
  location: class ContentBlockerHandler
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\content_blocker\ContentBlockerHandler.java:180: error: package Request does not exist

                            Request mRequest = new Request.Builder().url(urlHttps).build();
                                                          ^
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\content_blocker\ContentBlockerHandler.java:181: error: cannot find symbol
                            Response response = null;
                            ^
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class ContentBlockerHandler
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\content_blocker\ContentBlockerHandler.java:231: error: cannot find symbol
            Request mRequest = new Request.Builder().url(url).head().build();
            ^
  symbol:   class Request
  location: class ContentBlockerHandler
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\content_blocker\ContentBlockerHandler.java:231: error: package Request does not exist
            Request mRequest = new Request.Builder().url(url).head().build();

                                          ^
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\content_blocker\ContentBlockerHandler.java:232: error: cannot find symbol

            Response response = null;
            ^
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class ContentBlockerHandler
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\Util.java:201: error: package OkHttpClient does not exist
      OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
                  ^
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\Util.java:201: error: package OkHttpClient does not exist

      OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
                                                     ^
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\Util.java:210: error: cannot find symbol
      OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder
      ^
  symbol:   class OkHttpClient
  location: class Util
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
16 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_inappwebview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 27s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

**Configuration**
I have the following configuration:

**Flutter doctor output:**

```dart
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 2.3.0-17.0.pre.411, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

---

**Pubspec.yaml:**

```dart
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
  get_it:
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  lottie: ^1.0.1
  stacked: ^2.1.9
  firebase_core: ^1.4.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.0.1
  firebase_analytics: ^8.2.0
  pin_code_fields: ^7.2.0
  geolocator: ^7.1.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.6
  geocoding: ^2.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.6
  rflutter_alert: ^2.0.2
  sms_autofill: ^2.0.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.6
  flutter_tts: ^3.1.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.8
  flutter_icons:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/adarsh-technocrat/flutter-icons
  timelines: ^0.1.0
  scrollable_positioned_list: ^0.1.10
  in_app_review: ^2.0.2
  share: ^2.0.4
  connectivity: ^3.0.6
  cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
  youtube_player_flutter: ^8.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.0"
```

---

**Build.gradle file:**

```java
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

**Technical Details:**

- Device: ASUS Z01RD (mobile)
- OS: Android
- Version Android 10

**Already Tried Solutions**

I have already gone through a lot of searching for the solution on the internet and also tried some of my own tricks but all went in vain.

Here is the list for the same:

- Tried the solution mentioned here: https://github.com/sarbagyastha/youtube_player_flutter/issues/490
- I tried upgrading the gradle version.
- I tried running clean installs.
- I tried upgrading the complete app to null safety and hence using `environment: sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`
- Tried installing the flutter_inappwebview plugin explicitly through pubspec.yaml.
- Tried removing some other existing dependencies which I thought can be conflicting (like webview_flutter plugin).
- Tried upgrading all dependency list to the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Java 8](https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html), as it is recommended and stable. Make sure of both JRE and JDK should be version 8. Uninstall any other versions you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `youtube_player_flutter` package is using `flutter_inappwebview`. you can see it on the pub.dev or just running the command `$ flutter pub deps` on the project terminal.

To solve this you need to add `fluttter_inappwebview` under dependency_overrides in pubspec.yaml (If there is no dependency_overrides section in your pubspec.yaml create one under the dependency section).
The code will look like this

```
dependency_overrides:   
  flutter_inappwebview:
      git:
        url: https://github.com/rshrc/flutter_inappwebview
        ref: master
```

Also, don't forget to check the `minSdkVersion` in android/app/ build.gradle file.Change it as preferred by `flutter_inappwebview` .
Currently, it is `minSdkVersion 17`. Don't worry if it is higher than preferred by `flutter_inappwebview` .